# How to control LEDs wirelessly using an app made in Kivy?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on my A-Level computer science project and I need help. I am currently developing an app in Kivy, and I need to use this app to wirelessly control LEDs via a raspberry Pi and send SMS messages to phones (again, via the Pi). I also need to Pi to detect motion via a PIR sensor. I am not entirely sure how to go about this and I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me. I need to know what kind of hardware I will need and if anybody could point me in the right direction for the code, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What do you want to happen when motion is detected? Send a text warning about motion?

Comment: Also, are you on the same LAN as the RPI? That will make quite a difference.

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?